# Installing app through Android Studio on a physical device without WiFi nor usb cable

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a custom device with an `Android` operating system which I wrote an app for in Android Studio.

As mentioned [in the official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device?utm_source=android-studio-2021-1-1) there are `two ways` to run/debug an app on a `physical device` which none of them seem to be possible on my device.

One option is to use `WiFi` to connect. I didn't try this because the device seems to only support up to `Android 10`, and as stated this requires `Android 11` at least.

The other option is via `USB connection`. The problem with this one is that the device doesn't have the USB connections like phones have, but only the wide connection like a standard pc has.

Is there any way to debug (or at least install) my app on this device which both doesn't have Android 11 and doesn't have the standard USB entry like phones and other usual Android devices have (although it has a computer like `USB entry`)?

I was hoping for being able to debug on `bluetooth` or to transfer the installation files to the device but couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to any device with any Android version over wifi, if you are connected to the same network and you know the device's IP address. Simply try using `adb connect IP` to connect to device, where `IP` is the actual IP address of the device you are trying to connect.